# How to create dynamic call to javascript function

Tags: javascript

JavaScript question.  I'm completely drawing a blank this morning.

I have four functions:

```
function create_account1(){  // some stuff  }
function create_account2(){  // some stuff  }
function create_account3(){  // some stuff  }
function create_account4(){  // some stuff  }
```

I now have need to loop through some numbers and if a criteria is met, call the appropriate function. Since I don't know which number I'm on in the loop, how can I do this?

simple example:

```
for( var i=1; i<=4; i++ ){
  create+i+(); 
}
```

That does not work and I've tried variations, but can get it working.

Thanks for any suggestions.
johnC

Comment: `window['create_account'+i]()` but it would be better a different approach in your system

Comment: Sorry, typo - in my for loop, the call should read:
    create_acct+i+();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these function live in the global context?

If so, you could use this:

```
for( var i=1; i<=4; i++ ){
  window["create_account" + i](); 
}
```

FYI: If you want to test this in a jsFiddle, be sure to **not** use the *onLoad* or *onDomready* wrap settings of jsFiddle. If you try to use them, your functions will become nested ones which obviously don't belong to the *window* object anymore.

Comment: Thank you to 'chumkiu' and to 'ComFreek'.   Spot on!  That worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 function mainfunc (){
    window[Array.prototype.shift.call(arguments)].apply(null, arguments);
 }
```

The first argument you pass should be a function name to call, all the rest of the arguments would be passed onto the called function. In your case,

```
mainfunc('create_account1');
```

or

```
mainfun('create_account2', 'Name');
```

if you need to pass a name for `create_account2`.

Answer (score 1):

Please do by this:

```
 for( var i=1; i<=4; i++ ){
  var fnName = 'create_account' + i ;
  //create+i+();
  window[fnName]();
}
function create_account1(){

  alert('Hello');

}
```

Comment: its working @Tomzan , I checked it in browser,  alert('Hello'); its just a example::: Please code paste in you console then press enter then you see this function is working fine . you can do anything in your function right and thanks

Comment: After you changed it to window['name']() I can't disagree.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call function like this. I think you're facing design problem, the proper way to do it is something like this:

```
function create_account(accountID) {
    switch(accountID)
    {
        case 1: 
        {
            //account 1 logic.
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            //account 2 logic.
            break;
        }
        etc...
    }
}
```

And you call it like this

```
for( var i=1; i<=4; i++ ){
  create_account(i); 
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, but it's right in my opinion that the OP has possibly a design problem!

Comment: I didn't downvote but as I've already said, this doesn't answer the question! He wants a dynamic function call, not some pre-defined switch cases. "You cannot call function like this" <-- this is not true!

Comment: I think that the purpose of this community is to give the best solution, and if someone stuck because he's trying to make weird things, a correct way to do what he's trying to achieve may be better..

Comment: Yeah, but your solution isn't the right way either imho. The numbers aren't meaningful, it would be better to create constants.